# Mapping Icollection on intermediate tables on c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, icollection

I'm trying to figure out a way of mapping an icollection into a table but it throws me this errors:

Error 1:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' to 'elayer.c'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error 2:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type   EntityLayer

This is part of the code, if needed more for help would love to add, it's driving me crazy,

Mapping.cs

```
internal class CMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<c>
{
    internal CMapping()
    {

        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(200);

        this.HasMany(x => x.wc)
            .WithRequired(x => x.c)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.cid);

    }
}
```

c.cs

```
public class c: BaseEntity
{
    public int cid{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int link{ get; set; }
    public ctype Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection <wc> wcs{ get; set; }
}
```

wc.cs

```
public class wc: BaseEntity
{
    public int wcid { get; set; }
    public int wid{ get; set; }
    public int cid{ get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    public w w{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<c> c{ get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE -----
wcQueryService

```
public IEnumerable<wDto> FindwcByStoreIdAndwId(int storeId, int wId)
{
    using (var dc = this._cmsContextFactory())
    {

        var query = from wc in dc.wc
                    join c in dc.c on wc.wId equals c.wId
                    join w in dc.w on wc.wId equals w.wId
                    where wc.IsDeleted == false
                    && c.IsDeleted == false
                    && wc.IsDeleted == false
                    && wc.BrandId == storeId
                    && w.wId == wId
                    select new wDto
                    {
                        wwId = wc.wwId,
                        wId = w.wId,
                        wId = c.wId,
                        BrandId = wc.BrandId,
                        Videos = (from c in wc.w
                                  select new wTypeVideoDto
                                  {
                                      Text = c.Text,
                                      wId = c.wId
                                  }).ToList()
                                         };

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man you need to name your classes and variables better.  What a headache...

Comment: hahaha, it isn't the real names, sorry for that :(, but the would kill me if I post the real names

Comment: Alright, why is `c` property in your class `wc` collection? Shouldn't it be `public c c { get; set; }`?

Comment: I tried that, but c on the queryservice I have a collection of c's inside a collection of w (wc is the intermediate)

Comment: And when I do that link goes crazy

Comment: I added the Query Service, I know it's crazy with the replacements, sorry for that :(

Comment: As I understand, you have `w`, `c` many-to-many via explicit `wc` link table. `wc` should not have collections. `wc` should have single `w` and single `c`, while both `c` and `w` classes should have `ICollection<wc>`

Comment: @IvanStoev you are entirely right!, can you post it as an answer so I can check it as an answer? (you saved my sanity :D)

Comment: No worry mate, glad that the problem is solved. feel free to delete the post. cheers.